# Generate executable from simulink so it will accept input from command line

Tags: matlab, simulink

For example I have simple model

[image]

I want to send a command

```
>model.exe 1
```

and get an answer as stdout

Answer to comment: My input at first stage should be a constant maybe later I want it to be a time series(If I should use instead of input something else please suggest).The target it 64 bit windows

I did looked through documentation but didn't find any meaningful explanation if it possible at all or maybe If I want it I should change the generated code and add this functionality myself

Comment: What is the 1 being input in your example? Is it the gain value or the input signal? If it's the gain, what do you expect the input signal to be? If it's the input, how do expect to make it (generically) time varying?  More generally, the answer depends on what code generation target you are using, so we need to know that too.

Answer (score 2):

The only Windows executable code generation target that allows for specifying different signal and parameter values from those existing when the model is compiled is the [RSIM](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/rapid-simulations.html) target.

However, the new signals and parameters must be specified in a .mat file, and the name of the .mat file is passed as a command line argument to the executable using the `-i` and `-p` switches.

An example of changing inputs may be found at [Use MAT-Files to Feed Data to Inport Blocks for Rapid Simulations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/use-mat-files-to-feed-data-to-inport-blocks-for-rapid-simulations-0fa041a18ae7.html).  An example of changing parameters may be found at [Run Rapid Simulations Over Range of Parameter Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/using-rsim-target-for-parameter-survey.html)

The above example show how to create new .mat files from within MATLAB itself.  However they can be created in C-code too.  There are various examples of doing this, which are linked from [Table of MAT-File Source Code Files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/list-of-examples.html)

Comment: Thanks,So the best way to feed external data to simulation generated file is to use mat files?What about binary files?(I found blocks that can read and write to those files).Also I thought the possibility to use fopen and fread?

Comment: Another thing to consider that I want the results of simulation to be read by another program.

Comment: Note that I didn't say it was the best way, merely that that is the only code generation target that creates an exe and allows for signal and parameter tuning from the command line.  You can always just generate the C code from the model and wrap that into your own (possibly hand written) code to create your own executable or dll, in which case you can make it work any way you want.